# Querying two tables containing CLOB datatype

Tags: sql, oracle, clob

I have two tables: `Table1` and `Table2`. `Table1` has columns `RECORDID`, `DATASOURCETYPE` and `STRINGCLOB`, whereas `Table2` has columns `RECORDID`, `TIMESTAMP` and `CLICKTYPE`. I have written a query to find the clob XML string 'book' from the `STRINGCLOB` column, provided that it matches a given `DATASOURCETYPE`, as follows:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(stringclob, instr(stringclob, 'type>')+5
                        , instr(stringclob,'</type') 
                             - instr(stringclob, 'type>')-5
             ) r_type from Table1
 where DataSourceType = 'Source1'
   AND SUBSTR(stringclob, instr(stringclob,'type>')+5
                        , instr(stringclob, '</type')
                              - instr(stringclob, 'type>')-5
             )
     like '%book%'
```

Now, I would like to find and count all occurrences of '%book%' string from the `STRINGCLOB` colum (`Table1`) that were recorded in the last month (something like AND `TIMESTAMP > '01-Nov-12' AND TIMESTAMP < '01-Dec-12'`) and of `CLICKTYPE <> 'Type1'`. I am struggling with querying data from two distinct tables, any idea?

Thanks indeed,

I.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand the question, but if this is XML data why not use [`XMLType`](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/xmltype-datatype.php) and xpath etc?

Comment: Jack, thanks for your comment. I am not familiary with XML Type, but it looks like the right way to approach the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @ilariac:Can you please add FROM clause in your query .

Comment: @Gaurav thanks, I did not notice it was missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you get the count of the record_type having value as `book`.

```
WITH t
       AS (SELECT   '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                       <record>
                        <record_number>12345</record_number>
                         <record_type> book </record_type>
                       </record>'
                       STRINGCLOB
             FROM   DUAL
           UNION ALL
           SELECT   '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                          <record>
                            <record_number>6789</record_number>
                            <record_type> book </record_type>
                         </record>'
                       STRINGCLOB
             FROM   DUAL)
SELECT   COUNT (1) total
  FROM   t
 WHERE   xmltype (t.STRINGCLOB).EXTRACT ('//record_type/text()') LIKE '%book%';
```

**total**

2

Now,if you want to join with the table 2,based on record_id

```
 SELECT   COUNT (1) total
   FROM   table1 t1, table2 t2
  WHERE   xmltype (t1.STRINGCLOB).EXTRACT ('//record_type/text()') LIKE
            '%book%'
         AND t1.record_id = t2.record_id
         AND t1.DataSourceType = 'Source1'
         AND (TRUNC (t2.timestamp) > '01-Nov-12'
              AND TRUNC (t2.timestamp) < '01-Dec-12')
         AND t2.clicktype <> 'Type1'
```